# Not able to click on the webpage Link using HtmlUnitDriver but Same is working with FirefoxDriver. Why?

Tags: firefox, selenium, automation, htmlunit, webdriver

When I am trying to click on the Link using below line of code using `FirefoxDriver` it is working fine.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("More...")).click();
```

But when i use `HtmlUnitDriver` then i am getting below exception.

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: No link found with text: More...
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_24'
Driver info: driver.version: HtmlUnitDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElementByLinkText(HtmlUnitDriver.java:630)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$2.findElement(By.java:93)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver$4.call(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1198)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver$4.call(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.implicitlyWaitFor(HtmlUnitDriver.java:934)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElement(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1195)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElement(HtmlUnitDriver.java:377)
    at com.search.engine.BotwSearchEngine.isPageExists(BotwSearchEngine.java:154)
    at com.search.engine.BotwSearchEngine.searchCategories(BotwSearchEngine.java:82)
    at com.search.engine.BotwSearchEngine.main(BotwSearchEngine.java:189)
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that the link is not present on the initial load of the page, and added subsequently using JavaScript? If so, you might was to check that you have JavaScript enabled when you create the HTMLDriver instance: `WebDriver driver = new HTMLUnitDriver(true);`

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/HtmlUnitDriver

Comment: Not working. :( Getting this Exception. I think there is something wrong with the page/java script. `Exception in thread "main" ======= EXCEPTION START ========
EcmaError: lineNumber=[0] column=[0] lineSource=[function () {] name=[ReferenceError] sourceName=[onkeypress event for HtmlTextInput[<input name="mainheader1$Botwsitesearch2$q" type="text" id="mainheader1_Botwsitesearch2_q" class="form-search-input" style="width:193px;" onkeypress="if ((event.keyCode == 13)||(e.which == 13))`

Comment: `in http://botw.org/top/Business/] message=[ReferenceError: "e" is not defined.]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "e" is not defined.`